# What is stored in memcached?

Tags: java, memcached

What is actually stored in memcached when used for DB query caching.

If your answer is query result, then how do i invalidate an entry in the memcached if an update is made on any entity that the query is dependent on?

what about join queries? Is it ok if i cache them? how will i know if a table in the join query is updated or not, so i can invalidate the cache entry.

Also pls suggest some examples or articles.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287319/memcached-tutorial

Comment: @Tichodroma the question is in it's simplest form. FYI, suppose a join query result is stored with some key, how do i get those queries cached for which i have made the update on a constituent table?

Answer (score -1):

In memchached key/value pairs are stored in configured cache. When you store DB result set it storing `java.lang.Object`.

You can invalidate this value by using any memcached client methods. e.g. spymemcached client provides a method like `replace(String key, int expression, Object ob)` which says

> Replace an object with the given value (transcoded with the default transcoder) iff there is already a value for the given key. You can also delete old object.